# Mongodb query using "$gt"

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this task "Write a mongodb query to find the count of movies released after the year 1999" . I'm trying to do this with this different line codes in the picture bellow, none of them works. Any thoughts?

PS: the collection's name is `movies`, the columns are the `year` and `_id` of the movies.

These are the lines I'm trying:

```
docs = db.movies.find({"year":{"$gt":"total"("1999")}}).count()

docs = db.movies.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$year","count":{"$gt":"$1999"}}}])

docs = db.movies.count( {"year": { "$gt": "moviecount"("1999") } } )

docs = db.movies.find({"year":{"$gt":"1999"}})

docs = db.movies.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$year","count":{"$gt":"1999"}}}])
```

Comment: give a sample document from your collection,  else its hard to tell why doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an aggregate
try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4FCZCrhaGBM)

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "year": {
        "$gt": "1999"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": 1,
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$total"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The first stage of the pipeline is `$match`, it will filter only your documents with a year greater than 1999.

Then in the `$group` we will sum all the `total` variables.
The `"_id": 1`, is a dummy value because we are not grouping on any particular field, and we just want to sum all the `total`

Comment: take a look on the output bellow pls

Comment: is the year a int or a string ? Can you edit your question and add a sample of your data ?